# Converting complex nested list to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

One of the columns in pandas dataframe have below data:

input:-

```
   [(inventoryMeasureCode='Customer Order', measureValue=[(startDate=1632639600000, quantity=170.0, extensions={'nfcoType': 'PROMOTION'})])]
```

Now i want to convert this structure to multiple columns.
Tried many ways but failed.

What would be the correct way to convert the above data to multiple columns so that dataframe looks as below:-

```
inventoryMeasureCode startDate        quantity   nfcoType
Customer Order       1632639600000   170.0       PROMOTION
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Give   the  a proper input data so that we can pay around ....  like that it  is difficut to answer.

Comment: Where `Row` comes from? This is an instance of a class?

Comment: @Corralien yes  i am converting avro to pandas dataframe , so "Row" is probably coming after conversion , we can ignore "Row".

Comment: The problem now is your list is not valid. Raised `SyntaxError`. Your column contains real python lists or a strings?

Comment: Is the input a string - the whole construct isn't valid Python?